# Sympy substitution of x[i]*x[j] with x[i,j]

Tags: sympy

I have an indexed symbol `x` in Sympy and an expression which is a sum of second degree monomials like `x[1]*x[2] + x[3]**2 + x[4]*x[1]`. I would like to turn such an expression into `x[1,2] + x[3,3] + x[4,1]`, i.e. replacing `x[i]*x[j] -> x[i,j]`

There is an upper bound on the indices which may appear, so I could construct a large table hard coding each substitution. Is there a better way?

Responding to the comment - to create x I write

```
from sympy.tensor import IndexedBase
x = IndexedBase('x')
```

Comment: Could you show the code that you have used to create x?

Comment: Note that it might give `x[i, j]` or it might give `x[j, i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ordered to put the indices in order:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> i, j = symbols('i j', cls=Wild)
>>> x = IndexedBase('x')
>>> e = x[1]*x[3] + x[2]*x[1] + x[3]**2
>>> def new(o, x):
...  if o.is_Mul:
...   i,j=list(ordered([i.args[1] for i in o.args]))
...  elif o.is_Pow:
...   i = j = o.base.args[1]
...  else:
...   raise NotImplementedError
...  return x[i, j]
...
>>> e.xreplace(dict([(o, new(o, x)) for o in e.find(x[i]*x[j])]))
x[1, 2] + x[1, 3] + x[3, 3]
```

But a simpler way to do the same thing is to use a Piecewise result in the replace call:

```
>>> e.replace(x[i]*x[j], Piecewise((x[i,j],i<j),(x[j,i],True)))
x[1, 2] + x[1, 3] + x[3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` with a `Wild`.

```
In [1]: i, j = symbols('i j', cls=Wild)

In [2]: x = IndexedBase('x')

In [3]: e = x[1]*x[3] + x[2]*x[1]

In [4]: e.replace(x[i]*x[j], x[i, j])
Out[4]: x[1, 2] + x[1, 3]
```